# Problem about sentence construction from LoTR passage

Tags: sentence-construction

*It was the pride and wonder of the Northern Line that, though their power departed and their people dwindled, through all the many generations the succession was unbroken from father to son.*

*Also, though the length of the lives of the Dunedain grew ever less in Middle-earth, after the ending of their kings the waning was swifter in Gondor; and many of the Chieftains of the North still lived to twice the age of Men, and far beyond the days of even the oldest amongst us.*

I cannot understand the construction of the lower part of the text (from LoTR appendix).

I tried some ways to divide chunks but they didn't read smoothly within the context.

I assumed its meaning may be as following

Also, though the length of the lives of the Dunedain grew ever less in Middle-earth and after the ending of their kings the waning was swifter in Gondor, many of the Chieftains of the North still lived to twice the age of Men....

but I can't understand the funtion of the commas and semicolon and determine whether it's two sentence or one. And how much portion the 'though' include under its effect?

Please help! Thanks in advance:)

Answer (score 1):

*Though* introduces the first (dependent) clause, *length ... grew ever less*.

This is contrasted with the second (main) clause, *waning ... was swifter in Gondor*.

The semicolon serves as a 'hinge' which links the assertion that change was swifter in the Sougth to a description of the consequences: *Chieftains of the North still lived [longer]*

Paraphrase:

> The lives of all the Dunedain grew shorter everywhere in Middle-earth,
>   but after the line of kings ended this shortening was accelerated in Gondor.
>
> [Consequently]
>   the Chieftains of the North lived much longer than the men of the South.